# Let random variables $x, y$ be independent, then how to prove the rest of this?

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

Let random variables $X, Y$ be independent, then

$\text{Var}(XY) \geq \text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)$

I thought $\text{Var}(XY) = [E(X)]^2 \text{Var}(Y) + [E(Y)]^2 \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)$

but I don't know how prove the rest of this.

Could someone explain me that thing step by step how to get the answer to the task?

Sorry for bad format, but it's my first post on this website.

Comment: When you have that equality, then it is obvious, since $Var$, and $(E[])^2$ are $\ge 0$

Comment: How would you prove it in the special case where $E[X]=E[Y]=0$?

Answer (score 1):

$Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, similarly $Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2$

We have: $Var(XY) = E[X^2Y^2] - E[XY]^2$.

Since $X,Y$ are independent, we have independence of $X^2,Y^2$, too. In particular $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ and $E[X^2Y^2]=E[X^2]E[Y^2]$, so:

$Var(XY) = \mathbb E[X^2] \mathbb E[Y^2] - (\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y])^2 = \mathbb E[X^2]\mathbb E[Y^2] - (\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y])^2 + \mathbb E[X^2] \mathbb E[Y]^2 - \mathbb E[X^2]\mathbb E[Y]^2 = \mathbb E[X^2](\mathbb E[Y^2] - \mathbb E[Y]^2) + \mathbb E[Y]^2(\mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2) = \mathbb E[X^2]Var(Y) + \mathbb E[Y]^2Var(X) = \mathbb E[X^2]Var(Y) + \mathbb E[Y]^2Var(X) + \mathbb E[X]^2Var(Y) - \mathbb E[X]^2Var(Y) = Var(X)Var(Y) + \mathbb E[X]^2Var(Y) + \mathbb E[Y]^2Var(X)$

Since both $Var$ and $\mathbb E^2$ operators are $\ge 0$, then $Var(XY) \ge Var(X)Var(Y)$